Can C++20 modules be used without building a library?
I have the following code (source) that correctly builds only if I create a library:
/// main.cxx

import foo;

int main()
{
  foo f;
  f.helloworld();
  return 0;
}


/// foo.cxx

module;
#include <iostream>
export module foo;

export class foo {
public:
  foo() = default;
  ~foo() = default;
  void helloworld();
};

void foo::helloworld() { std::cout << "hello world\n"; }

With this CMakeLists.txt file, which creates a library, everything works:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(std_module_example CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_library(foo)
# Add the module file to the library
target_sources(foo
  PUBLIC
    FILE_SET CXX_MODULES FILES
      foo.cxx
)
add_executable(hello main.cxx)
target_link_libraries(hello foo)

With this CMakeLists.txt file, which creates an executable, I have an issue:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(std_module_example CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_executable(hello main.cxx foo.cxx)

This is the error message I get:
bin> CXX=clang++ CC=clang cmake -GNinja ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 18.1.3
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (0.6s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pietrom/Documents/dev/test/modules/bin
bin> ninja -v
[1/6] "/usr/bin/clang-scan-deps-18" -format=p1689 -- /usr/bin/clang++   -std=c++20 -x c++ /home/pietrom/Documents/dev/test/modules/main.cxx -c -o CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.cxx.o -MT CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.cxx.o.ddi -MD -MF CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.cxx.o.ddi.d > CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.cxx.o.ddi.tmp && mv CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.cxx.o.ddi.tmp CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.cxx.o.ddi
[2/6] "/usr/bin/clang-scan-deps-18" -format=p1689 -- /usr/bin/clang++   -std=c++20 -x c++ /home/pietrom/Documents/dev/test/modules/foo.cxx -c -o CMakeFiles/hello.dir/foo.cxx.o -MT CMakeFiles/hello.dir/foo.cxx.o.ddi -MD -MF CMakeFiles/hello.dir/foo.cxx.o.ddi.d > CMakeFiles/hello.dir/foo.cxx.o.ddi.tmp && mv CMakeFiles/hello.dir/foo.cxx.o.ddi.tmp CMakeFiles/hello.dir/foo.cxx.o.ddi
[3/6] /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_ninja_dyndep --tdi=CMakeFiles/hello.dir/CXXDependInfo.json --lang=CXX --modmapfmt=clang --dd=CMakeFiles/hello.dir/CXX.dd @CMakeFiles/hello.dir/CXX.dd.rsp
FAILED: CMakeFiles/hello.dir/CXX.dd /home/pietrom/Documents/dev/test/modules/bin/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/CXXModules.json CMakeFiles/hello.dir/main.cxx.o.modmap CMakeFiles/hello.dir/foo.cxx.o.modmap 
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_ninja_dyndep --tdi=CMakeFiles/hello.dir/CXXDependInfo.json --lang=CXX --modmapfmt=clang --dd=CMakeFiles/hello.dir/CXX.dd @CMakeFiles/hello.dir/CXX.dd.rsp
CMake Error: Output CMakeFiles/hello.dir/foo.cxx.o provides the `foo` module but it is not found in a `FILE_SET` of type `CXX_MODULES`
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

What is the meaning of the message: "CMake Error: Output foo.cxx.o provides the foo module but it is not found in a FILE_SET of type CXX_MODULES"?
How can I fix it?
This is my software stack:
Linux Ubuntu 24.04, LLVM/clang 18.1.3, cmake 3.28.3

I find obvious that the error message means that you need to put C++ module files into CXX_MODULES file set, like you do that in your first CMakeLists.txt.

@Tsyvarev, OK, now it works. I thought that CXX_MODULE file set was only needed when creating libraries. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.
